# Реинжиниринг бд

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Имеется программа на PHP, но для нее нет бд, коллеги обещали скинуть дамп баз данных, но когда это произойдет, неизвестно... Существует ли способ как-то выдрать структуру БД из кода? (речь о десятках баз данных, в каждой из которых десятки(сотни) таблиц)?

Comment: в субд оракл есть служебные таблицы используя которые можно получить информацию о структуре субд: таблицы, поля с типами, индексы итд итп. С помощью не очень сложного скрипта можно вывести практически всю структуру субд. думаю такие скрипты можно найти на просторах интернета вполне вероятно что и для вашей субд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего где-то в коде зашита вся схема со структурой табличек. Так обычно делают :)

Попробуйте поискать в файлах по словам "create table"

Comment: а я так не делаю)))) на продакшене это вообще бредовая идея) при условии, что "обычно" делают запрос в любом случае типа "create table if not exists" это очень накладно по ресурсам... либо отдельный исталлятор, но обычно этим заведует отдельная группа dbadmin, которые при деплое выполняют чистый sql с изменениями db...

Comment: Схему часто включают в код для тестов. Ну и для того, чтобы версионировать её, модифицировать вместо с кодом, проверять соответствие базы и схемы на старте и тп :) 

Жаль что вы так не делаете.

Comment: нет, эти не зашили, 100%... (((
репозиторий из гита...

Comment: Ещё вариант - поискать используется ли в коде какой-нибудь ORM. Если да, то можно заставить его запустить схему бд на основе мапинга :) Если в коде мало SQL строчек, то возможно ORM таки есть, и реверс инжиниринг возможен.

Comment: ORM как раз есть, на нем все построено (в основе Zend framework 1)
но я не представляю как можно заставить запустить его схему бд на основе маппинга

Comment: скорее всего вам сюда http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html#database-schema-generation

Comment: Вот это интересно, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Отчасти, читаь запросы к БД и надеяться, что в этих запросах задействованы все поля всех таблиц :) Ну и времени это займет оооочень много... ИМХО не стоит оно того.

Comment: @thunder - мне однажды поставили такую задачу, вывел на экран все запросы к БД и начал восстанавливать потихоньку, за 5 часов управился. Таблиц 20 было.

Comment: индексы всякие имхо только методом тыка можно выставить... а тут десятки дб и сотни таблиц в каждой...